# Feedback gem for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a feedback form on my site. On clicking the feedback button on left side of the screen the form with idea, problem of question appears. Ofcourse I can code it on my own but it's quite boring. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have several choices, my personal one would be going with https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails and then render the form as a partial with a modal container. That will make the whole process really simple and fast for you.

Also, you can install something like https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form gem that will allow you to easily customize your form, assuming that you're using RoR. Otherwise, discard the gem information but you can still use the bootstrap to load the form. This will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If it's mostly the styling your looking for. I personally like these two free options:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Slide-Out-Tab-Feedback-Widget-Feedback-Me/

OR

http://codecanyon.net/item/usernoise-modal-contact-feedback-form/full_screen_preview/3461759

You then have to implement them with `simple_form` an `ActionMailer` (or saved to the database) to get the intended result.

There also is specific gem [my-feedback-form](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/my-feedback-form/), but it's added value is unclear to me. I prefer keeping my libraries to a minimum.